# eclipse installation in linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to install the eclipse IDE for c++ developers. I have downloaded the tar.gz from the eclipse and unzip/unarchived it using tar -xzvf... but now when I double click, or run eclipse nothing happens. I have done this before using the same method and it worked. I dont know why nothing happens now.

I also am aware of the sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform method. But I do not want to install the eclipse platform, just the IDE for c/c++ developers.

any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Have you set JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME variable ?

Comment: You don't need setting any environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try `chmod +x eclipse` in a terminal or run it from terminal: `./eclipse`.

**Edit:**

With the information of your comments in this answer, you have a 32bit system and your eclipse is a 64bit version. You can't run 64bit applications on a 32bit system.

So you have to download the 32bit version of eclipse (or virtualize an 64bit system with VMWare, for example).

Comment: when I tried ./eclipse  I get cannot execute binary file...

and the chmod did not change that fact

Comment: Then you might have downloaded the 64-bit version and your system is 32-bit. Edit your question and add there the results of `uname -a` and `file ./eclipse`.

Comment: I believe it is 64bit linux with the 64bit eclipse.. 
uname -a 
Linux bryanU 3.2.0-27-generic-pae #43-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 6 15:06:05 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

file ./eclipse 
./eclipse: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped

Comment: so apparently this is a 32 bit system? is it possible to install a 32bit os on a 64bit processor? i have the i3930k?

Comment: You have a 32bit system and an eclipse of 64bit. You can't run 64bit applications on a 32bit system. You have two options: download a 32bit version of eclipse, or virtualize an 64bit system (with VMWare) and run your eclipse.

Comment: And yes, It's possible to install a 32 bit OS on a 64bit processor, but not a 64bit OS on a 32bit processor.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse, you need to have a JVM up and running, since it's a Java application. You can install the JRE of your choice (I personally use OpenJDK 6 since I also do Java development).